# Flutter local notifications doesn't redirect to relevant screen when app is killed

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, android-notifications

I am using [`flutter_local_notifications`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) in a Flutter app to schedule notifications at certain times.

When I click on the notification, while the app is running it works as expected and takes to the relevant screen; but when the notification is clicked when the app has been killed, it takes to the home screen instead.

Since, this notification is scheduled automatically rather than on user-action, I am doing it in a function rather than a widget. So, I do not have `context`. To work around that, I use `GlobalKey` of type `NavigatorState`.

```dart
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
navigatorKey.currentState?.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('notification clicked'),
    ),
  );
}));
```

**Second approach I tried is using a stateful widget**

```dart
class Noti extends StatefulWidget {
  const Noti({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  NotiState createState() => NotiState();
}

class NotiState extends State<Noti> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initNotification();
  }

  Future initNotification() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('bolt');
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: selectNotification,
    );
    const notDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('1', 'Scheduled Review',
            channelDescription: 'Review reminders at scheduled time'));
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(1, 'Scheduled Review',
        'Every Minute', RepeatInterval.everyMinute, notDetails);
  }

  Future selectNotification(String? payload) async {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((ctx) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('notification clicked'),
    ),
  );
})));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

This `Noti` widget I inserted at a random place in my home page, so that its `initState` gets called.

The same thing happens here too; i.e., on clicking the notification when the app is dead, I get redirected to the home screen rather than a screen with title `notification clicked` as is the logic here. When the app is active, it works fine though.
I have tried this on both versions `8.2.0` & `9.0.0` of the said library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadn't seen this note:

> Note: from version 4.0 of the plugin, calling initialize will not trigger the onSelectNotification callback when the application was started by tapping on a notification to trigger. Use the getNotificationAppLaunchDetails method that is available in the plugin if you need to handle a notification triggering the launch for an app e.g. change the home route of the app for deep-linking.

Changing `initialRoute` based on `notificationAppLaunchDetails` solved it.

```dart
final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  final didNotificationLaunchApp =
      notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;
final initialRoute = didNotificationLaunchApp ? '/second' : '/first';
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to put this code? Inside the main? Or a custom class?